# android studio error when I upload an image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-image

When I upload an image and try to run my app, I am getting this errors [image] .

Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users**\AndroidstudioProjects**\app\src\main\res\drawable\page2.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

What I can do?

thanks

Comment: Don't post your exceptions as a link. Especially not as an IMAGE. Post the exception and the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

[Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1 (ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965398/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-ic-launcher-png-error-duplicate-fi)