# android studio is giving an error when i build

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build an android app for the google playstore and when i change the build type to "release " from debug,it gives me the error bellow:

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bridging\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: post `build.gradle` file here.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Did you define correctly android.signingConfigs object in your gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1 (ic\_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965398/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-ic-launcher-png-error-duplicate-fi)

Comment: After i created my app, i built the apk but it gives me those errors

Comment: @Ironman do you mean this file
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'

Comment: @JohnsonMizzyDubula see my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your compile **SDK version** must **match** the `support library's` major version.

Since you are using `version 23` of the support library, you need to compile against `version 23` of the Android SDK.

Alternatively if you can continue compiling against `version 22` of the Android SDK by switching to the latest `support library v22`.

**Update :**

[image]

see in the screen both are same 23 you have to check.

if comileSdkVersion 22 and make round corner all to 22.